# Spring - Missing Required Library - hibernate3-3.2.3.GA.jar

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/) to understand the Spring and Hibernate. After I added the hibernate dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
</dependency>
```

I got this error

```
Project 'SpringExample' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\gmuniandy\.m2\repository\hibernate\hibernate3\3.2.3.GA\hibernate3-3.2.3.GA.jar'  SpringExample       Build path  Build Path Problem
```

.

I have downloaded the jar file and placed in the folder manually but the issue still remain. Please advice.
[image]
EDIT
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is an wrong writing in thy pom.xml: **Instead of "ga" use "GA"** as Ragu already wrote.

Did you try already the [downloadable project](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Spring-Hibernate-Example.zip) from the Website?

And what looks strange to me, I found no hint about case-sensitivity on maven.org, though maven uses case-sensitive match when matching against property values. [Referring to Maven Model](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_property)

May I suggest, that you follow this tutorial?
[Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/)

At the bottom of the Article you will see a complete pom.xml which obtains the required and correct versions of libs from a inherited pom.

It should keep your pom short and simple. So you can better concentrate on your task rather than bothering around with libs at an early stage of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean up your local Maven repository and resolve dependencies again?

Comment: I've deleted the .m2 folder an rerun the project. It still show me the same error

Answer (score -1):

version is wrong -correct one  3.2.3.GA , In mvn repository you can search specific jar maven dependency.

Comment: how to check on the mvm repository? I'm very to Spring and Maven,

Comment: Do you mean they have incorrect version in repository? Here we have correct spelling http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.3.ga

Comment: i have changed the decency as per the link. `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
</dependency>`. But the issue still same

Comment: <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId> <version>3.2.3.GA</version> </dependency>